# Fire a Google DoubleClick tag when a user submits the form

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, double-click

I have a custom web form on my page, I'm trying to fire a Google DoubleClick tag when a user submits the form successfully (next page is a payment gateway so I can't drop a tag on this page unfortunately)

The form has the validation:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
```

I am wondering if anyone has experience of firing a submit rule on this kind of form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the validation returns true, a standard GTM Form Submit Trigger should work fine as after the JS is done it still submits the form "normally" as opposed to a JS submit like `this.submit`.

Alternatively, if you have easy access to that JS, just add this to it before the `return true`:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({'event':'form_submit'});
```

and then make a `Custom Event` Trigger that looks for the `form_submit` event as a firing trigger to your DoubleClick Tag.